# All parameters defaulted to "tunable" by export to FMU from Dymola, but should be "fixed"

Tags: modelica, dymola, fmi

All parameters are always exported as "tunable" by FMUexport from Dymola. In many places this cannot be changed to "fixed" at all, because (sub)components from libraries are locked against it. So our next  tool tries to use degrees of freedom which do not exist. Is it possible to reverse the behaviour so that all parameters are initially set as "fixed"? Or is it possible to set all parameters to "fixed" at once, even those in library blocks?

Comment: Please provide more details: Which Dymola version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two flags in Dymola come to my mind that could have an effect:

```
Evaluate = true
Advanced.EvaluateAlsoTop = true;
```

Both can be set via the GUI:
[image]

They do have influence on the definition of the variable in the FMU's XML file. They change "causality" and "variability". Though I'm not sure they do exactly what you want.

Likely it would make sense to set only `Evaluate = true` and propagate all the parameters that shall be "tunable" to the top level...